# Eclipse native launcher with non-OSGi application

Tags: java, eclipse, osgi, equinox, eclipse-pde

Is it possible to use the Eclipse native launcher with a Java application that isn't Equinox-based? For example a simple Swing application contained in myapp.jar.

I suppose that if this is at all possible the procedure should be the same on all the supported platforms and that one should act on the .ini files that come with the native launcher.

Comment: @Elliott Frisch do you know how?

Comment: How far along are you? I'd start with `java -jar org.eclipse.osgi_3.2.0.jar -console`

Answer (score 1):

From the ['about' tag for OSGi](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/osgi/info)..

> OSGi is a specification for a Java component framework with enforced modularity. It provides a comprehensive model to build applications out of smaller, reusable parts. *Though it works with **any Java code**, its advantages are best obtained by using its strong modularity.*

As an aside:  For deploying Java desktop apps., the best option is usually to install the app. using [Java Web Start](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/java-web-start/info).  JWS works on Windows, OS X & *nix.

Comment: The fact is that I don't want to make the application Equinox-based.

Comment: Umm.. so it is ***any Java code*** as opposed to ***Java code based on Equinox?***  I don't quite understand why you made that comment.